# Is it possible to enable all the text fields at once in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, disabled-control

I have multiple text fields which I need to enabled or disabled at once using Java Swing.
Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'll need to write a method to iterate over the references to these fields (if they're not explicitly stored in a collection, you can filter the list of children of their parent component) and call `setEnabled(false)`

Comment: Personally, I'd simply use something like [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) (for Java 7) or [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) for earlier versions of Java.  This would allow you to paint, essentially, a component based glass pane which you could use to "disable" the contents

Answer (score 6):

If all the `JTextFields` are on a single container, you could do :

```
for (Component c : container.getComponents()) {
   if (c instanceof JTextField) {
      c.setEnabled(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you put them all in a linked list / array list you could have a method to loop though it and enable / disable. This is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

It will be hard to maintain global list of all components and iterate over all references. Let's say you need to notify all text fields to become enabled or disabled without breaking loosely-coupled nature of your system (I assume you are interested to keep your application maintainable).

My suggestion is:

1. Sub-class JTextField
2. Start using EventBus to decrease coupling (you can start with any implementation, [this one](http://eventbus.org/) is simple enough)
3. In your JTextField sub-class subscribe to receive **change_state** event
4. Use your own JTextField whenewer you want to have enable/disable supported
5. Generate **change_state** event from any part of your application

Please note, there will be(should be) only two places related to the requested functionality:

- event triggering (can be button action listener)
- event processing (JTextField sub-class)

Do not spread event processing logic over your application. Happy coding.